# Equivalent form of $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ for a nonlinear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vectors, systems-of-equations

[The general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#General_form) of a system of linear equation is $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$. But what is the equivalent general form for a system of nonlinear equations?

Comment: $\mathbf f(\mathbf x)=\mathbf 0$.

Comment: The general form of a system of equations (linear or nonlinear) is $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$, but I am not aware of any notation which will restrict to just *nonlinear* equations.

Answer (score 1):

A system of nonlinear equations always can be written as
$$A(\vec{x})=\vec{b},$$
where $A$ is a nonlinear vector operator.